# JBOSS - How to ignore the hash check

Tags: java, build, jboss, war, ear

In `standalone.xml`

```
<deployments>
        <deployment name="xxx.ear" runtime-name="xxx.ear">
            <content sha1="xxxxxxx"/>
        </deployment>
</deployments>
```

Is there a way to tell JBOSS to ignore the hash so I don't have to re-upload the EAR to the server each time I change one line of code?

Comment: I may be wrong but I doubt it’s dynamic like that, unfortunately.

Comment: @notyou even if I had to restart the server, it would be okay with me